# How to add identifier column based on date in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table (here is a sample of it):

```
name date_time
jon  10/01/2019
jon  11/01/2019
jon  12/01/2019
jon  25/01/2019
sam  03/04/2019
sam  18/04/2019
sam  19/04/2019
sam  29/04/2019
fred 02/02/2019
fred 03/02/2019
fred 12/02/2019
fred 13/02/2019
```

There is a name column var char and date_time column which is date format in postgresql.

I would like to create a new column which allows me identify if the user was in a "session".

A "session" is the first 10 days from which the user first logged a date_time value, anything after those first 10 days is another "session".

It does not mean a new identifier every 10 days, it means only 2 identifiers need to be made - one for the first 10 days from the first date_time value and one from the 11th day onward.

for example it should look something like this:

```
name date_time  session_identifier
jon  10/01/2019 jon_session_1_id
jon  11/01/2019 jon_session_1_id
jon  12/01/2019 jon_session_1_id
jon  25/01/2019 jon_session_2_id
sam  03/04/2019 sam_session_1_id
sam  18/04/2019 sam_session_2_id
sam  19/04/2019 sam_session_2_id
sam  29/04/2019 sam_session_2_id
fred 02/02/2019 fred_session_1_id
fred 03/02/2019 fred_session_1_id
fred 12/02/2019 fred_session_2_id
fred 13/02/2019 fred_session_2_id
```

As you can see taking the first example of the user jon:

I want to create a identifier (i called it jon_session_1_id) here and this is repeated for the 10 day period from the first date_time value taken - which is 10/01/2019 so the jon_session_1_id will be repeated as the session_identifier up until 20/01/2019 then it will change to be job_session_2_id.

so on and so forth for the other names in the table.

How can this be done in SQL? I have used a case when statement but no result came close!

Comment: Can you add the row (fred, 11/11/2019), and adjust the result accordningly?

Comment: no - that is manually labour intensive

Comment: I don't understand what fred is not 1-1-1-2 given that same is 1-2-2-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results for Fred and Same are inconsistent.  In one case a 9 day lag results in a new session.  The other allows a 10 day lag.  I am interpreting Fred's as a typo.

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_dt >= date_time - interval '10 day' then 0 else 1 end) over
          (partition by name order by date_time) as session_number
from (select t.*,
             lag(date_time) over (partition by name order by date_time) as prev_dt
      from t
     ) t;
```

Because of the use of `sum()` this starts the counting at 1.  You can also write this as:

```
select t.*,
       1 + count(*) filter (where prev_dt < date_time - interval '10 day') over
              (partition by name order by date_time) as session_number
from (select t.*,
             lag(date_time) over (partition by name order by date_time) as prev_dt
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=baeadc1596968875e54d9d914fb7afc1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right - the session_number should change to the value 2 when the date has increased by 10 days - e.g. go from 10/01/2019 session_number is 1 - then when it is 20/02/2019 it changes session_number to the value 2 - how does this work?

Comment: This is actually not close to the desired output - can you please elaborate?

Comment: Can you set up a db fiddle of some sort?  This logic should be doing exactly what you want.

Comment: I will do it now

Comment: Can't seem to get a dbfiddle connection - its basically the table you see above you - it does not work though the code you gave!

Comment: @DataScience . . . "not close to the desired result" is rather strong, for something that differs in one row, where you would seem to have a typo in your question.

Comment: Okay thanks for the dbfiddle - but how can I ensure that I get a unique session number value for each person? currently it just has the numbers 1 and 2 - thats not unique to that person and their session?

Comment: @DataScience . . . Your sample results are already concatenating the user name to a session sequence number.  It is not asking for a separate sequence for each person.

Comment: how can I get the concatenation as the example in the sample?

Comment: I am just baffled on what causes some people to downvote ostensibly correct answers without commenting why.